# Find unique entries in List<Object[]>

Tags: java, unique, hashset

```
List<Object> listObj = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
listObj.add(new Object[]{1,"abc",new Date(21/1/2001)});
listObj.add(new Object[]{1,"abc",new Date(21/1/2001)});
listObj.add(new Object[]{2,"acc",new Date(21/1/2001)});
Set<Object[]> unique = new HashSet<Object[]>();
unique.addAll();
```

I´m expecting to get:

```
{1,abc,21/1/2001},{2,acc,21/1/2001}
```

Instead I get:

```
{1,abc,21/1/2001},{1,abc,(21/1/2001},{2,acc,21/1/2001}
```

How to find unique entries in this example?

Comment: HashSet has nothing to do with `Comparable`. It just uses `hashCode` and `equals`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arrays in Java don't have the concept of equality that would allow this to work.  You need to define a custom class with a number, string and date and implement equals/hashCode yourself to allow this to work.

Comment: The above is the correct way to do this. However, you could also use a `Map<String, Object[]>` and use the `Object[].toString()` as the key. I believe this will work because the `toString` for arrays includes all the elements of the array (up to a point). This is a "smelly" solution and again, the "correct" one is the one stated above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `TreeSet` initialized with a custom `Comparator` that does the check you need; there is no way for this work with arrays and the default comparator.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to use a `Set`. I would strongly recommend creating a class to capture your int, string and date object

```
public class Foo {
    private int num;
    private String letters;
    private Date date;
}
```

Then you can override methods `equals` and `hashCode` to get expected behaviour from your set

Answer (score 0):

I would encapsulate all data in the object array to a POJO.
In the POJO you can define your own **equals** method. e.g

```
public class Bean {
    private int i;
    private String l;
    private Date d;
    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public String getL() {
        return l;
    }
    public void setL(String l) {
        this.l = l;
    }
    public Date getD() {
        return d;
    }
    public void setD(Date d) {
        this.d = d;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((d == null) ? 0 : d.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + i;
        result = prime * result + ((l == null) ? 0 : l.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof Bean))
            return false;
        Bean other = (Bean) obj;
        if (d == null) {
            if (other.d != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!d.equals(other.d))
            return false;
        if (i != other.i)
            return false;
        if (l == null) {
            if (other.l != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!l.equals(other.l))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in Java do not override `hashCode()` and `equals()` thus comparing two arrays with the same contents (with the same length and equal elements) unexpectedly yields false.

If you use `List<Object>`, it should work fine. You can take advantage of `Arrays.asList()` utility.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a thin wrapper around `Object[]` that would provide appropriate `hashCode()` and `equals()`. The two methods can very easily be implemented in terms of [`Arrays.deepHashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepHashCode%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and [`Arrays.deepEquals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
public class Cmp {

    public static class ObjArray {
        private final Object[] arr;
        public ObjArray(Object[] arr) {
            this.arr = arr;
        }
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Arrays.deepHashCode(arr);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            ObjArray other = (ObjArray)obj;
            return Arrays.deepEquals(arr, other.arr);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<ObjArray> listObj = new ArrayList<ObjArray>();
        listObj.add(new ObjArray(new Object[]{1,"abc",new Date(21/1/2001)}));
        listObj.add(new ObjArray(new Object[]{1,"abc",new Date(21/1/2001)}));
        listObj.add(new ObjArray(new Object[]{2,"acc",new Date(21/1/2001)}));
        Set<ObjArray> unique = new HashSet<ObjArray>();
        unique.addAll(listObj);
        System.out.println(unique);
    }


}
```